# Difference between timestamp variable and time variable

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table in postgresql (table1):

```
timestamp1  timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
variable1 integer,
timestamp2  timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
```

I want calculate the timestamp2.

Note that variable 1 is of type integer in table 1, but in practice is a time variable defined in hours

The timestamp2 is defined by difference of timestamp1  and variable1 
(timestamp2= timestamp1 – variable1)

For example,

```
2013-02-06 07:00:00  -  5 = 2013-02-06 02:00:00
2013-02-06 09:00:00  - 12 = 2013-02-05 21:00:00 
2013-02-06 12:00:00  - 4.5  = 2013-02-06 07:30:00
```

How to do this calculation (of timestamp2)  in postgresql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select timestamp1 - interval '1 hour' * variable1
from table1
```

Answer (score 1):

Postgres understands the number as time:

- 5   -> 05:00:00
- 12  -> 12:00:00
- 4.5 -> 04:30:00